# Not found error when using WebClient to send a GET request

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I'm trying to send GET request to my server, using WebClient and get error for "Not found". In C++ the same request works fine. My URL looks like:

```
"https://www.example.com/something/something&param1=data1&param2={}"
```

... and the request look like

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string res = client.DownloadString(url);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So it returns a 404? You would not see that if it was an SSL issue as its raised after a connection to the server is established.  Presumably the URL works in a Web Browser? Execute the request with *Fiddler* running and see if that tells you anything after comparing with a successful request.

Comment: I tried the request with postman and it works

Comment: Assuming this is correct in the actual code? https://www.example.com/something/something& (the first & should be a ?)

Comment: @KennethIto i changed it, and still get "Bad Request" (400)

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded! i was missing the headers.

my URL looks like "https://www.example.com/something/something?param1=data1&param2={}"

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
client.Headers.Add("Accept-Version", "4");
client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "v4.1.0.0");
string res = client.DownloadString(url);
```

Thanks for the help